# "this" mandatory for member access from inside the class body in PHP?

Tags: php, this, member

Coming from C++ I am used to be able to access class members directly in the body of their class, however, this doesn't seem to work in php - simple setters and getters fail to work unless explicitly using `$this->` to access them. Setters seem to set to a temporary object that gets discarded and getters generate an error of trying to access non-existing objects.

Is there a way to directly access members inside the class body without the `this` keyword in php?

Comment: No, usually when switching languages it tends to be impossible to continue writing in the new language as if it was the previous one. Also there is no way to refer to variables without the `$` sigil, although C++ doesn't have that either.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? $this is current instance, so unless you want to access static methods, it is the way to go.

Comment: @Tadeck Shorter to write - In a lot of languages, `$this->` is implicit.

Comment: @Tadeck - in C++ `this` is implicit - you always access the current instance members.

Comment: @lanzz - it is a big annoyance for me - I started with C and C++ and since learning those I got so used to the syntax it was a bit tedious to bother with all those little cosmetic changes when I learned JS, AS and now PHP. I do realize for some changes there is a good reason behind, but many of those differences appear to be unnecessary, just for the sake of breaking commonality between all those languages, despite the fact they all derive from C syntax.

Comment: @troelskn: So the only reason OP asks for it is to save him from writing `$this->`. I suspected that, but in PHP it makes the difference and despite all the disadvantages (and bad design decisions) in PHP I consider it rather an advantage.

Comment: @Tadeck - yep, for me PHP is a little verbose - the `$` in front of every identifier, the need of explicit `this` for member access - it is stuff I am really used to not have to do from all the C++, and I often find myself instinctively not doing it and getting errors and bugs.

Comment: @ddriver You're arguing from the position that all languages start with C and then proceed to modify its parts. This is rarely the case. PHP's origins are closer to Perl, which already had the `$` sigil, the main purpose of which is to allow easy expansion of variables within strings. PHP's OOP on the other hand is a completely deranged beast, borrowing with abandon from vastly different sources; but the mandatory `$this` stems from the deranged "implicitly local" rule for PHP variables: with optional `$this`, you could not have function-local vars, they would always be instance members.

Comment: @lanzz - I suppose the absence of a compilation phase mandates this syntax to distinguish between function locals and instance members, PHP performance is slow as it is, having extra checks to determine the object being referred will only make interpretation slower. One thing I think makes no sense is always interpreting code instead of compiling it to bytecode upon first execution, that would make subsequent executions way much faster.

Comment: @ddriver You're giving PHP too much credit. The actual problem lies in two very stupid decisions in PHP: 1. Requiring developers to declare _anything_ before using it is a big no-no, so you're always allowed to just stuff a new member into any instance at run-time; and 2. Developers are too dumb to understand global variables, so _all_ variables are function-scoped unless _explicitly_ declared as global, and there is no way to explicitly declare them local. So if you use a bare variable in a method, there is no way to tell if it should become a method-scope local, or a new instance member.

Comment: And the variable scope insanity predates the introduction of OOP in PHP, so it is an inherited situation that will be carried on forever for backwards compatibility (never mind that every major release breaks lots of backwards compatibility) and to avoid confusing the majority of PHP devs who would not understand what's going on if the scope rules suddenly change.

Comment: @lanzz - I get what you mean, I have this "bad design" feeling all over php, I still struggle with justifying an OOP use for PHP, maybe a few convenience classes, but it is so obviously a procedural language. Too bad the market demands all those inefficient, half-baked languages that began as simple scripting languages that were forced into being something they should not really be. I cannot shake the feeling there should be a "one language to rule them all" - it is certainly doable, it is just like... it would be too good for this world gone so wrong...

Comment: [One language to rule them all](http://xkcd.com/927/), eh?

Comment: @lanzz - just because things are this way doesn't mean this is the only way things can be. The problem is mostly with the industry that is all about money making, with every major player doing everything possible to establish and conform users to his own solution. It would take a paradigm, focused mainly on developer benefits to come up with a universal solution that is simple and flexible to use, boasting both a high performance static native side, interconnectible with a dynamic, reflecting runtime and various stages of JIT compilation to either VM bytecode or hardware native. It is doable!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is not. Setting an undefined variable will create it for the current scope, so that's what you're observing. (This is not a member variable though) - You can even read from an undefined variable, in which case the value will be null. This will generate an `E_NOTICE` though, so it's not considered good style.

Answer (score 0):

Please read http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php give a code snippet to see the exact problem you are facing